# Monero's wallet RPC validate_address is not working using PHP or CURL

Tags: monero-wallet-rpc

All the other RPC methods are working for me, except the `validate_address` one, which always returns an error. I tried both curl (CLI) and PHP, neither of them work, they return the same error:

```
{"result":null,"error":{"code":-32700,"message":"Parse error"},"id":null}
```

If anyone can help, it would be much appreciated.

Comment: You'll get better help if you edit your question to include the curl and php code that is failing for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to assume you're copying the example from the [docs](https://www.getmonero.org/resources/developer-guides/wallet-rpc.html#validate_address), which has an error in that `params` should read `"params"` (quoted).

A corrected and working example looks like:

```
$ curl localhost:18084/json_rpc -d \
    '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":"0","method":"validate_address", "params":{"address":"42go2d3XqA9Mx4HjZoqr93BHspcMxwAUBivs3yJKV1FyTycEcbgjNyEaGNEcgnUE9DDDAXNanzB16YgMt88Sa8cFSm2QcHK","any_net_type":true,"allow_openalias":true}'
{
  "id": "0",
  "jsonrpc": "2.0",
  "result": {
    "integrated": false,
    "nettype": "mainnet",
    "openalias_address": "",
    "subaddress": false,
    "valid": true
  }
}
```